# $k[t^2-1,t^3-t]$ is the algebra of polynomials such that $f(1) = f(-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The question is basically in the title. The normalization of the nodal cubic is given by
$$k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))\to k[t]:x\mapsto t^2-1,\,y\mapsto t(t^2-1)$$
whose image is the polynomial algebra
$$k[t^2-1,t^3-t]$$
Clearly any element of this algebra satisfies $f(1) = f(-1)$. I want to show the converse. Here's my work so far.

If $f(1) = f(-1)$, then $t-1$ and $t+1$ divides $f(t) - f(1)$, so $t^2 - 1$ divides $f(t) - f(1)$. Write $f(t) - f(1) = (t^2-1)g(t)$. If $g(t) = b_0 + b_1t+\cdots+b_mt^m$, then
$$f(t)-f(1) = b_0(t^2-1) + b_1t(t^2-1) + t^2(t^2-1)\sum_{j= 0}^{m-2}b_{j+2}t^j$$
It seems that I would need to show then that
$$h(t):=\sum_{j=0}^{m-2}b_{j+2}t^j$$
is divisible by $t^2-1$, i.e. $h(-1) = h(1)$ and sort of continue in this fashion, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: By subtracting constants we may assume $f(1)=f(-1)=0$. Now $f(t)$ divides $(t-1)(t+1)$. Thus it suffices to check $t^n(t^2-1)$ is a polynomial of $t^2-1,t^3-t$ for all $n\ge0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\{ f\in k[t],f(1)=f(-1)=0\} = (t^2-1)k[t]$$

So the algebra $A$ of polynomials such that $f(1)=f(-1)$ is $$A=k \oplus (t^2-1)k[t]=k\ \bigoplus_{n\ge 0}\ (t^{2+n}-t^n)k$$

$B=k[t^2-1,t^3-t]$ is a subalgebra of $A$.

$B$ contains $t^2$ and $t^3-t$ so $B$ contains all the $t^{2+2n}-t^{2n}$ and $t^{3+2n}-t^{1+2n}$,

whence $B=A$.